# Django model formset performance

Tags: django, performance, django-forms, modelform, formset

I have little perfomance issue with Django 1.4.2 and PostgreSQL 9.1. I want to create model fromset with form created like this:

**forms.py**

```
class AcknowledgeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['acknowledge', ]
        widgets = {'acknowledge': forms.CheckboxInput()}


AcknowledgeFormset = forms.models.modelformset_factory(Attendance, form=AcknowledgeForm, extra=0)
```

for model with few ForeignKeys

**models.py**

```
class Attendance(models.Model): #500k rows in DB
    zamestnani = models.ForeignKey('people.Zamestnani',  related_name='attendance') #~1k rows
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day) #~2.5k rows
    acknowledge = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class VacationAcknowledgeView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "presence/presence_vacation_acknowledge.html"
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(VacationAcknowledgeView, self).get_context_data()
        person = Person.fromRequest(self.request)
        first_day = date(date.today().year, 1, 1)
        days = Attendance.objects.filter(acknowledge=None,  day__date__gte=first_day, zamestnani__osoba=person)
        context['formset'] = AcknowledgeFormset(queryset=days)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #next line is screwed
        formset = AcknowledgeFormset(request.POST)
        #never been there....
        return super(VacationAcknowledgeView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I can create it, render it, everything seems ok, but assigning data from POST leads to server freeze for very looooong time (litteraly hours) for single object.

After short digging around I personaly blame model formset, because when I create it and process it just like single form, everything working as expected. But I have no idea how to fix/evade this.

Thank for any reasonable advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that there are ~500,000 rows in your database for the `Attendance` models. In Django, when the `queryset` parameter is not specified for a `ModelFormSet`, it includes all objects in that model. Django is probably fetching all 500,000 rows of data.

You need to figure out the queryset for your `ModelFormSet`. E.g.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Attendance.objects.none()
    formset = AcknowledgeFormset(queryset=queryset, data=request.POST)
    # continue with your regular code execution
```

The documentation contains a section for the queryset of a `ModelFormSet`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet